# xwatermark in xepersian does not work together?

Tags: incompatibility, persian, xwatermark

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[printwatermark]{xwatermark}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xepersian}
\newwatermark[allpages,color=cyan!30,angle=45,scale=0.5,xpos=0,ypos=0]{$Wellcome$}
\newwatermark[allpages,color=gray!30,angle=90,scale=0.5,xpos=-50,ypos=0]{$Wellcome$}
\begin{document}
\begin{persian}

نظریه اعداد از مباحث ریاضی است.

\end{persian}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I tried a workaround: to create a watermark with tikz+fancyhdr, but I had no luck.

Comment: The `bidi` package (loaded by `xepersian`) supports `draftwatermark` but not `xwatermark`; maybe you can do with this other package.

Comment: @egreg:Thanks.I want to have more watermark in my document,it seems i should use tikz package to do it.

Comment: @Malipivo-Thanks.I want to have more watermark in my document,it seems i should use tikz package to do it.

Comment: @egreg,can you help me?i can not solve my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `xwatermark` package is not among the ones supported by `bidi`. You can use `draftwatermark`, instead. Perhaps it's not as customizable as `xwatermark`, but it works.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{draftwatermark}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xepersian}

\SetWatermarkText{\latin{Draft}}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{persian}

نظریه اعداد از مباحث ریاضی است.

\end{persian}
\end{document}
```

[image]